# How do i execute the ScalaTest testcases written in my Azure Databricks notebook from Azure Devops build/release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, scalatest, azure-databricks

Below is a basic "ScalaTest" testcase I've written in my Azure Databricks Notebook. I would like to execute this testcase from Azure DevOps Build or release pipeline and view the test results.

I searched for resources but no luck(Reference to one of the forums which talks about the same issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d31ef5b-5b18-4305-ad09-0107e47891be/automated-testing-in-azure-databricks?forum=AzureDataFactory)

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
class SampleTestSuite extends FunSuite 
{
test("1 equals 1") 
{
    assert(1 == 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can ScalaTest be executed via command-line? If so, you can run the test via command-line task in a self-agent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run ScalaTest through Maven: [ScacleTest Maven plugin](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin)

Then, it would general Junit test result and you can publish test result file through [Publish Test result task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

This thread may benefit you: [Scalatest in maven: JUnit results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730260/scalatest-in-maven-junit-results)

Comment: I believe these steps would work if the tests are developed in an IDE. But in my case Tests are written only in Databricks notebook as some of these tests need to perform operations on Delta table(this is not possible if written in an IDE as there are [limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#limitations)). I have steps to achieve this using [Pytest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops#define-your-build-pipeline) do we have anything similar in ScalaTest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @saravanair Are you able to run test through command line? https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner

Answer (score 0):

Use `AnyFunSuite` instead of `FunSuite`

Comment: For reference, you can use this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67971085/how-to-run-a-spark-scala-unit-test-notebook-in-databricks)