# How to run a Spark-Scala unit test notebook in Databricks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, scalatest

I am trying to write a unit test code for my Spark-Scala notebook using scalatest.funsuite but the notebook with test() is not getting executed in databricks. Could you please let me know how can I run it?

Here is the sample test code for the same.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.Assertions._
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._
import com.fasterxml.uuid.Generators
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession, Column}

class ImsLoyaltyTest extends AnyFunSuite {
  test ("Date Format Checker") {
    val sampleIpData = Seq(
      Row("india","hello","05-03-2021","14","50"),
      Row("india","hello","15-06-2021","14","50"),
      Row("india","hello","05/06/2021","6100","50"),
      Row("india","hello","05-31-2021","14","50")
    )
    
    val sampleIpSchema = new StructType()
      .add("a", StringType)
      .add("b", StringType)
      .add("c", StringType)
      .add("d", StringType)
      .add("e", StringType)
    
    val sampleIpDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(sampleIpData), sampleIpSchema)
    
    assert (sampleIpDF.collectAsList() == sampleIpDF.collectAsList())
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly create the object for that test suite & execute it.
In IDE you're relying on specific runner, but it doesn't work in the notebook environment.

You can use either the `.execute` function of create object ([docs](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/invoking_execute)):

```scala
(new ImsLoyaltyTest).execute()
```

but it could be better to use the `.run` method of ScalaTest shell ([docs](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_shell)) - you can control color output, run multiple tests, etc.:

```scala
import org.scalatest._

nocolor.durations.stats.run(new ImsLoyaltyTest)
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying... I have tried both of the methods but now it is throwing error `AbstractMethodError: Method $line5e46612c7a4b4f0bb06179c2e65f20f147/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$ImsLoyaltyTest.org$scalatest$Assertions$_setter_$assertionsHelper_$eq(Lorg/scalatest/Assertions$AssertionsHelper;)V is abstract` .... I am using scala 2.12 and scalatest 3.3.0-SNAP3

Comment: I have changed the scalatest version from 3.3.0 to 3.0.5 and AnyFunSuite to FunSuite... it worked like magic... @Alex Thanks again

Comment: Scalatest usually is a part of databricks runtime, so you don’t need to install it explicitly - just check with `ls -ls /databricks/jars/*test*`